# Can not pass Http response to Ios Side - InvalidMutabilityException

Tags: kotlin, swiftui, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

I am fetching data on common code, and pass the "Login" class to loginViewModel (Ios side).
But I am getting this error :

kotlin.native.concurrent.InvalidMutabilityException: mutation attempt of frozen kotlin.collections.HashMap@3b3cea8

API :
'''

```
suspend fun login(email: String, password: String, recaptchaTokenResult: String?): Login
{
    val url = "${Keys.URL}/api/login"
    val response: Login = httpApiClient.submitForm(
        url = url,
        formParameters = Parameters.build {
            append("email", email)
            append("password", password)
            append("recaptcha_token_result", recaptchaTokenResult ?: "")
        },
        encodeInQuery = false
    )
    return response
}
```

'''

ApiViewModel :
'''

```
@Throws(Exception::class) suspend fun login(email: String, password: String, recaptchaTokenResult: String?) : Login?{
    try
    {
        return api.login(email,password,recaptchaTokenResult)
    } catch (e : Exception) {
        return null
    }
}
```

'''
swiftUi:
'''

```
let loginSuccess = loginViewModel(api: ApiViewModel()).login(email: email, password: password, re: nil)
        if loginSuccess == true {
          progressVisibilty = false
          nextView = true
        }
```

'''
loginViewModel :
'''

```
let api : ApiViewModel
  init(api : ApiViewModel) {
    self.api = api
  }
  func login (email : String, password : String, re : String? = nil) -> Bool{
    api.login(email: email, password:password, recaptchaTokenResult: "", completionHandler: { response, error in
      var auth_tokrn = response?.account.authToken
       
    })
     
    return true
  }
}
```

'''

Login class :

```
@Serializable
class Account(
    @Serializable(with = ByteArrayAsStringSerializer :: class) val id: ByteArray,
    @SerialName("first_name") val firstName: String = "",
    @SerialName("last_name") val lastName: String = "",
    val email: String? = null,
    val phone: String? = null,
    @SerialName("mobile_phone") val mobilePhone: String? = null,
    @SerialName("timezone") val timeZone: String? = null,
    @Serializable(with = LocalDateAsStringSerializer :: class)  @SerialName("created_at") val createdDate: LocalDate? = null,
    @Serializable(with = LocalDateTimeAsStringSerializer :: class)  @SerialName("deleted_at") val deletedDate: LocalDateTime? = null,
    @SerialName("auth-token") val authToken: String? =null,
    @SerialName("smartlook_key") val smartlookKey: String,
    @SerialName("intercom_id") val intercomId: String,
    @SerialName("intercom_secret") val intercomSecret: String,
    //var roleMatrix: Role = Role.create()
)
@Serializable
class Login(
    val account: Account
)
```

Comment: I can't see problems in the code you've shared. please provide full stack trace. first of all you need to remember that you can't use 'var' is your kotlin shared side(excluding delegated properties), so you can search for any 'var' if your project, according to you exception `var HashMap` in your case

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin native uses  strict concurrency model. It will freeze (lock mutation) any resource if you move it to another thread. If you attempt to mutate such a  resource, you'll get this error. Freezing is recursive (I highly recommend reading some materials about this topic). I suspect that some variable in `Login` class is mutated after moving to another thread but you didn't provide `Login` implementation. Nice trick to find out the problem is to use [ensureNeverFrozen](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.native.concurrent/ensure-never-frozen.html) function. I would use it on `val response: Login` , you should be able to find out why the object is freezing.

Comment: Sorry, I am new in KMM

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use ensureNeverFrozen?

Comment: I also added my Login class into the original post, thanks!

Comment: It seems that `Login` class isn't the issue, my guess would be `httpApiClient.submitForm`. You can use `ensureNeverFrozen` on any object, so you could call it like this `response.ensureNeverFrozen()`